# add mutiple columns using pnpjs core in SPFx App

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I am using pnp js to create a list to be used by my sharepoint application. i tried provisioning it using the sharepoint framework schema but i am really have issues with it and have raised an issue for it (https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1253) . now i am trying to create a list using pnp js as a workaround. my code looks something like this:

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.ensure("listName").then((ler : ListEnsureResult) => {
                    listEnsureResults = ler;

                        if (!ler.created) {

                        resolve(ler.list);
                        return Promise.reject(LIST_EXISTS);
                        }


                        return ler.list.fields.addText("Field1");

                })
```

i want to add multiple columns but i am always getting an error in adding multiple fields.

Comment: what's the error  ?

Comment: Hi @GautamSheth, sorry i didnt mean error. just no columns are being created, no error messages are showing

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple fields to list as below in SPFx:

```
public addFieldsToList(listname: string): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.all([      
      pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listname).fields.addText("MyField1"),
      pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listname).fields.addText("MyField2"),
      pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listname).fields.addText("MyField3"),
      pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listname).fields.addText("MyField4"),
    ]).then((response) => {
      return response;
    }, (error: any) => {
      return error;
    }).catch((error: any) => {
      return error;
    });
}
```

You just need to call this method and pass your list name.

Comment: hey @pageFPT, did you try and integrate this code ? is it working for you ?

Comment: Hi @Gautam , sorry for getting back to you just now but i had intermittent issues with this "{"odata.error":{"code":"-2130575305, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Save Conflict.\n\nYour changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes."}}}"